# Doubling the argument in a Fourier series

Tags: fourier-series

I'm confused by the hint on the following exercise from Peter Olver's *Introduction to Partial Differential Equations*:

> Suppose $a_k, b_k$ are the Fourier coefficients of the function
> $f(x)$. To which function does the Fourier series $$\frac{a_0}{2} +
> \sum_{k=0}^\infty [a_k \cos(2kx) + b_k \sin(2kx)] \enspace
> \text{converge?}$$ *Hint*: The answer is *not* $f(2x)$.

Does it refer to the fact that the period of the new series is $\pi$, so it's not the Fourier series of $f(2x)$ on the entire interval $[-\pi, \pi]$, but instead only on $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$?

Comment: you are on the right track; then for $\pi/2 < x \le \pi, 2x$ lies outside the basic period interval so you need to bring it back etc

Comment: Thank you, I think I got it!